# When citing a publication with more than one author as subject of a sentence, are verbs plural or singular?

Tags: verb-agreement, citation

Which is correct in this sentence: "enumerate" or "enumerates"?

> Jacobs and Watanabe (1966) **enumerate(s)** possibilities that cause change in phase path length, including change in intensity of the geomagnetic field and change in electron density spatial distribution.

"Enumerates" treats the paper being cited as the (singular) subject, while "enumerate" treats the authors as the subject. Which is correct?

Comment: Your summary is well done: *"Enumerates" treats the paper ... while "enumerate" treats the authors as the subject*.

Comment: ... People free from arbitrary constraints (mandatory style guides) may, if they subscribe to notional agreement, select the verb form they consider more appropriate (see @Yosef's comment here). But style guides / institutions may instruct differently. From Sven's answer, CMoS seem to have a very idiosyncratic set of 'rules'. Essentially (1) ask for in-house practice in house; (2) globally, this is POB.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - can you explain POB please.

Comment: There's no 'one correct answer'; University A and University B (10 miles away) may have different practices and marking policies. Style Guide C and Style Guide D will often disagree. Sven quotes CMoS, which seems to invent a stinker of a rule. 'CMoS is saying that "Abramowitz and Saunders (2005)" is really a compressed form of "Abramowitz and Saunders (Abramowitz and Saunders 2005)'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the following comment in *The Chicago Manual of Style*, sixteenth edition (2010), you might well think that "Jacobs and Watanabe (1966)" should be interpreted as a singular entity:

> **15.27 *Syntactic considerations with text citations*.** An author-date citation is a form of bibliographic shorthand that corresponds to a fully cited work; it does not refer to a person.

It would seem that unless "Jacobs and Watanabe (1966)" *isn't* an author-date citation, it must be a short-form reference to a single entity—something like "L. Jacobs and T. Watanabe, *Our Friend the Atom* (Cambridge, Mass.: Harvard University Press, 1966")—and therefore ought to be construed as a singular subject in the sentence that the poster asks about.

But CMoS doesn't support that conclusion at all. Consider this excerpt from guideline 15.24 ("Text citations in relation to surrounding text and punctuation"):

> Where the author's name appears in the text, it need not be repeated in the parenthetical citation. Note that the date should immediately follow the author's name, even if the name is used in the possessive. ...
>
> > [Example:] Fiorina et al. (2005) and Fischer and Hout (2006) reach more or less the same conclusions. In contrast, Abramowitz and Saunders (2005) suggest that the mass public is deeply divided between red states and blue states and between church-goers and secular voters.

If CMoS had thought that "Abramowitz and Saunders (2005)" was "an author/date citation," it would have used the singular verb "suggests" rather than the plural "suggest" as the following verb. That it did not do so proves that CMoS dos not consider expressions of the form "Abramowitz and Saunders (2005)" to be "author/date citations."

This point, in fact, is the at the heart of the sentence in guideline 15.27 that follows the one I quoted above:

> Note how, in the examples in 15.24 and 15.25, the wording distinguishes between authors and works.

CMoS is saying that "Abramowitz and Saunders (2005)" is really a compressed form of "Abramowitz and Saunders (Abramowitz and Saunders 2005)"—where the first occurrence of "Abramowitz and Saunders" identifies the two people as authors and the second occurrence identifies "Abramowitz and Saunders" as part of "Abramowitz and Saunders 2005," which is in turn a short form of the cited work written by the two authors. So the first "Abramowitz and Saunders" is plural because it refers to the two authors as two people, and the second "Abramowitz and Saunders" is singular because it acts as part of a short-form reference to a single piece of writing.

The confusing thing here is that even though "Abramowitz and Saunders" functions in two very different ways outside the short-form parenthetical and inside it, CMoS says that you don't have to repeat the authors' names inside the parenthetical to make the short form accurate and acceptably complete.

Applied to the poster's case, CMoS's advice is to use a plural verb after the reference to *Our Friend the Atom*:

> Jacobs and Watanabe (1966) **enumerate** possibilities that cause change in phase path length, including change in intensity of the geomagnetic field and change in electron density spatial distribution.

The rationale is that "Jacobs and Watanabe" refers to the two authors of the written work, while "(1966)" stands for "(Jacobs and Watanabe 1966)," which is the short form of the full citation to the (singular) work *Our Friend the Atom*.

Comment: I'd say that it may be well to avoid CMoS here. It seems to adjust rules to shoehorn in edge cases. And in any case, an individual institution may [well] not agree here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: CMoS's advice on this question is rather difficult to make sense of, and its reasoning isn't terribly persuasive. Nevertheless, as a copy editor, I found its take quite interesting, and the poster's question is a good (and by no means rare) one. If I have time later today, I'll check some other style guides and see whether they address the same question. If they have any useful advice, I'll add it to my answer and try to develop a survey-of-the-style-guides answer that indicates the range of recommendations offered by influential reference works.